# Save python output into variable

Tags: python

I have file with bitarray that looks like this:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000
```

I need to make a sum of bits according to their position in the bitarray: (second bit, second bit + 7, second bit + 14). I tried the code below, but it made a sum only of the first printed value. Can you please guide me on the problem?

```
    lines = [line.strip() for line in open('test.txt')]
    bitp = range(1,len(lines[0]),7)
    for i in lines:
        for p in bitp:
            bitsum = sum(int(a) for a in i[p])
```

Comment: You set the size of `bitp` with the first line _only_, are all the lines the same length?

Comment: Do you have several bitarray lines in the file? Could you please explain "second bit, second bit + 7, second bit + 14" in a more comprehensive way?

Comment: @Hooked yes, it's have the same size

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Looking at the code makes this obvious, he want these chars: `line[1::7]`

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: I need sum of the bits in specific positioins: 1,8,15,23,30,etc (so it's position+7)

Comment: @ms4py: this is a very simple problem which can be well defined in very simple words. The thread opener did not manage to do this. John: for each line and independently of the length L and values of the bitarray you want to look at the numbers at positions 1+7i for i=0,1,... why do you write "second bit+" or "position+" or "according to their position"? The problem, in simpler words: "I'd like to sum up the numbers at position 1,8,15,... in this string:..."

Comment: @John: "Save python output into variable" is a bad title. "Sum up numbers occurring in string" may fit better.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Ack for both comments ;-) But why don't you edit the title, I like your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to store a sum per line? In this case you need a list:

```
bitsums = list()
with open('test.txt') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        bitsums.append(sum(int(c) for c in line.strip()[1::7]))
```

Comment: Thank's! it's work perfectly. So, the problem was with stripping and list function.